# KEYBOARD freeze in ubuntu 20.04.03

Tags: keyboard

Laptop keyboard is not working when I switch on the laptop.Keyboard Language is added but then also it is not working . I had uninstalled the os and reinstall it but then also same problem is occuring. In Libre office nothing is typing . What are the ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Is a external keyboard working? Is your notebook one functional in grub menu?

Comment: No sir external keyboard is also not working.  I don"t know whether it is one functional in grub menu . How to see that whether it is functional in grub menu.

Comment: Hm https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time